# Is it possible to set specific space area types with hotkeys?

Tags: python, interface, keymap

For example, I'd like to set a custom hotkey to change a window to `shader editor` *specifically*.

The way it works right now is that you have major types of area types and you cycle through their different versions. But I don't want to cycle, I want to set a shader editor.

[image: keybinds that cycle through types]

I know it's possible with Python, but I'm not sure if it's possible with just the user interface? And I'm not sure how would I implement a python script into my entire program if I had to, I'd probably need to code an addon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like by default you are only able to change the hotkeys to cycle through editor modes, or switch to the space if it's the only one in that space type.

However, it's really easy to make your own operators to accomplish simple tasks like this.

Switch to the *Scripting* workspace, and at the top click *Templates > Python > Simple Operator*.

[image: Location of simple operator template]

Then in one of the other windows, perform the actions you want your new operator to accomplish.

You'll see in the info bar that when you switch to the Shader editor, blender is setting your `bpy.context.area.ui_type` attribute to "ShaderNodeTree".

[image: info bar in python console]

So copy that line and plop it into the execute section of your operator. Before the `return {"FINISHED"}`. We can also remove the part `bpy` from the beginning, since the execute method is already getting context from the operator class.

We can also clean up the rest of the template, and get rid of alot of unnecessary stuff, to get it ready to use long term.

[image: Operator cleanup]

We also need to grab a snippet from another template, the *Addon Add Object* template. Copy, the part at the top that looks like:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "New Object",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}
```

Paste into your script and edit it to match your operator. Most of it can be left blank. But it's necessary to include it to install your script as an addon.

The final result should look like:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Switch to Shader Editor",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
#    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object", # Don't need to inlcude this because it's not in  menu
    "description": "Switches Directly to Shader Node Editor",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Screen",
}


import bpy

class SwitchToShaderEditor(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Switches Directly to Shader Node Editor"""
    bl_idname = "screen.switch_to_shader_editor"
    bl_label = "Switch to Shader Editor"

    def execute(self, context):
        context.area.ui_type = "ShaderNodeTree"
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SwitchToShaderEditor)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SwitchToShaderEditor)
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Then save this file somewhere you can remember, save it as something like "switch_to_shader_editor.py". Then go to *Edit > Preferences > Addons > Install*, find that file and double click it to install it.

You should see it pop up into your addons, check it to activate it.

Where you set the keymap is totally dependent on what current context you're dealing with, so it's important to think carefully about where you set your hotkey. (If you set it in *3D View (Global)* for instance, if you were hovering your mouse in the UV editor and tried to use the hotkey, it wouldn't work. The context matters.)

So, with this in mind, go to Keymaps > Screen > Screen (Global) and scroll to the bottom and click "Add New".

In the field where it says "none" replace that with the value from "bl_idname" in your operator script. it should look like:

[image]

Set whatever hotkey you want. Then save your preferences. Close that window, and test it out in the viewport. It should be working.

You now have your very own custom operator with hotkey!

There's alot more to cover about addon creation, but this process can basically be followed for 75%-80% of any process you want to turn into an Operator.

Comment: if this works (and i don't know)....but then Martys answer is just wrong.... ;)

Comment: I tested it as I was writing it. Marty's answer is basically the first section of my answer. Where operator attached to the current is not able to do this by default. But when you create your own operator you can basically do whatever you want.

Comment: @Jakemoyo This is similar to what I was preparing but I'm surprised it works, (and yes, it does work), because I thought setting `ui_type` should only work if you're already in the right space type, so I thought you'd have to make the call to `space_type_set_or_cycle` and then make this call.  Any idea how this actually works?

Comment: Omg you're the best! Just finished implementing this. You saved me like a good week of research and fighting basics! I didn't even know there are templates. I'm incredibly impressed you wrote it out like this. I'm going to develop it further :) Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlexM Glad to help! "Teach a man to fish" as they say.

Comment: @MartyFouts `space_type_set_or_cycle()` is looking for an enum of different space_types, which from what I can tell is something that is an operator that exists solely within the python realm of blender, basically an operator that makes a call to change the UI, whereas setting the context makes a call to the C end of Blender and changes the context directly. But the enum that you have to work with is predefined by the python code that makes up the UI. changing the context essentially has nothing to do with that.

Comment: The `space_type` arg in the method calls for an enum in 'EMPTY', 'VIEW_3D', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR', 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR', 'CLIP_EDITOR', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR', 'GRAPH_EDITOR', 'NLA_EDITOR', 'TEXT_EDITOR', 'CONSOLE', 'INFO', 'TOPBAR', 'STATUSBAR', 'OUTLINER', 'PROPERTIES', 'FILE_BROWSER', 'SPREADSHEET', 'PREFERENCES']  Which you can see corresponds directly with the `space_ **.py` files in the [bl_ui](https://github.com/blender/blender/tree/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui) module. So this operator seems to be built directly around these spaces.

Comment: basically I try to write the attribute in the console and if it doesnt give me a `AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute .. is read-only` then I go ahead and use that in my operator lmao. :D

Comment: @Jakemoyo Setting the context is a Python operation, and doesn't call C; but since most of the UI is written in Python that's usually OK.  What happens is that the next UI update basically reruns all of the code that draws the interface, and the code simply draws the UI that matches `ui_type`, blissfully unaware that anything had changed since the last call.  My confusion stems from why that doesn't result in a mismatch with the space type of the area. Maybe I'll look into it later.

Comment: _BUG Alert_  In your execute function, don't use `bpy.context`.  You need to execute the code in the context that the operator was called in.  Just use `context`.

Comment: big brain Martyyyy, good looking out!